# What are the differences between Accordion pattern and Disclosure pattern?

Tags: uiaccessibility

Apart from keyboard interaction, are there any major differences between Accordion and Disclosure patterns? Why does aria authoring practice have two different topics for logically similar show/hide components?

Answer (score 0):

[Aria-practices for Accordion](https://w3c.github.io/aria-practices) says,

> An accordion is a ***vertically stacked*** set of interactive headings that each contain a title, content snippet, or thumbnail representing a section of content.

An Accordion is a stack of **Disclosures**, aligned either vertically or horizontally, that mostly contains a list of nav items or nested disclosures.

While a Disclosure itself is an independent pattern implementing ***show/hide*** functionality.

Try to compare the keyboard accessibilities of [Accordion](https://w3c.github.io/aria-practices/#keyboard-interaction) and [Disclosure](https://w3c.github.io/aria-practices/#keyboard-interaction-8). One of the accessibilities in an accordion is if a new Header is clicked to view its hidden panel, then the previously opened panel must be closed